# How to fill in data in an input field using Javascript directly on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question has been asked a lot it seems on Stack Overflow but none of the solutions seem to be working. I am developing a web application where I have to fill in data in data fields on page load. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datetime" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("pageload",function(){
//for fill field
document.getElementById("datetime").value = "here is value";
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

For some reason, when I load the page, no data gets filled in, does anyone see the reason for it?

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon: Regarding your last edit, please have a look here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321191/2675154.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need jQuery. Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="datetime" value="" />

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById('datetime').value = 'here is value';
    };
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Please be sure to accept the answer if it has answered your question.

Comment: jQuery version in case: `$(function() { $('#datetime').val('here is value'); });`

Answer (score 0):

What version of jquery are you using?  Looks like pageload might deprecated and you should use pagecontainerload

Or better yet use the $(document).ready or .load methods?

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery it's called `document ready` event... So use the below syntax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //for fill field
 $("#datetime").val( "here is value");
});
```

Note the inner line of code has been changed.. This is the Jquery way of doing the same thing... 
You can also use this Shorthand to `$(document).ready(function(){` 
That is `$(function(){`