# Open a webpage in new tab and feed the form automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to open an external webpage when my page loads and would like to feed the details in the form in the external webpage automatically.

I know i can load the page with the onload() jquery inbuild function but i am not sure how to feed the external site form from my page with the details automatically.

```
window.onload = function () {
    load();
};

function load() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
    document.getElementById("name").value = "my name";
    document.getElementById("age").value = 28;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a dom element in a new window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880468/how-to-get-a-dom-element-in-a-new-window)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fill in data in an input field using Javascript directly on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673634/how-to-fill-in-data-in-an-input-field-using-javascript-directly-on-page-load)

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible cross-origin. Your page and the new page must be on the same domain.

Comment: @Bartu Not really. this is setting the value of a form in external page from my webpage

Answer (score 0):

```
function load() {
    var newTab = window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
    newTab.document.getElementById("name").value = "my name";
    newTab.document.getElementById("age").value = 28;
}
```

Assign your new window to a variable, and then you can refer it like I did!

Comment: ... That actually works? Isn't this, like, cross-site scripting?

Comment: @Fly Ah.. I did notice it's actually cross-origin... This works for same-origin for sure.